# How to build SQL query in arcpy using script variable?

Tags: arcpy, sql, query

I am trying to build a simple query where a feature layer field needs to be smaller than a certain number and another feature layer field needs to be bigger than a variable previously created in the script.

I know the following query (comparing a feature layer field with 2 strings) works fine.

```
> query = "ESTATE LIKE '{0}' OR ESTATE LIKE '{1}'".format('Node Live%','Node%Planned%')
```

So, I thought the following line would be correct:

```
> query = "gridcode < '{0}' AND Shape_Area > '{1}'".format(2,thres_area)
```

But it seems it isn't

NOTE: 'gridcode' and 'Shape_Area' are two feature layer fields and 'thres_area' is a script variable (integer) previously created.

Any idea what would the correct sintaxis be like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying a number but the value is treated like a string (because of the single quotes). Try

```
query = "gridcode < {0} AND Shape_Area > {1}".format(2,thres_area)
```

Comment: That was exactly it